# Iphone X space after Header in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, iphone-x

I did all the needed updates and added the needed code to meta in index.html, but I still get white space at the bottom of the header before the content section starts. Please see screenshot. Also, it appears like the Title is being cut.

Here is my meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

My HTML:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Saved</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

My Ionic Info:
cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
ios-sim    : 5.0.12 
Node       : v7.10.0
npm        : 4.2.0 
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using `WKWebView`?

Comment: I think I am. Where can I double check it?

Comment: In the `config.xml` file, check if you have the `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` plugin installed, or if something related to `UiWebView` / `WkWebView` is there

Comment: Yes, I've got this <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.16" />. So I guess I'm usinig WkWebView as needed. I also do recall upgrading to it from UIWebView a month or so ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my problem was that in App.scss I've explicitely changed the height of the Toolbar as follows:

```
.toolbar-background-ios { 
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 70px;           //This was the problem
}
```

By removing the height attribute, all works perfectly well for oth iPhone X and older iPhone 7 plus.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the issue. Please mark this answer as accepted when it's available so we can close the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate if you ever want to change the height of the navigation bar, you set it directly in your `variables.scss` so it can be set globally like:

```
$toolbar-ios-height: 70px;
$toolbar-md-height: 70px;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Very first thing to check is the Meta that should be like this

name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"

And if it does not resolve your issue then try to update the status
bar plugin.
Run the following command.

- ionic cordova plugin add
  https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git

but before doing that remove the previously installed status bar
plugin and then install the above it will surely fix your problem.

References
GitHub link : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git

If the issue still Persists then Kindly check your Global.SCSS file and look for the following

- .platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen)
  and find the toolbar-ios in that and adjust the header properties according to your requirements.